# Creature Horror Movie about Mermaids

Tags: story-identification, horror, mermaids

*This is going to be a tough one. I apologize in advance for knowing no more of this movie than a TV trailer.*

Some time between 2010 and 2016, I saw an announcement for a creature horror movie involving mermaids on German TV. The film was going to run a few days afterward, hence it was not entirely new at that time. However, from the visual quality of the film, I also don't think the film could have been much older than from the 2000s. (Quite certainly not among the 1980s horror movies occasionally shown on that channel.)

Also, I am pretty sure it was not an originally German movie. (The trailer being shown on a TV channel as an announcement of an upcoming film shown on said channel, this probably means the trailer I saw was not necessarily an "official" trailer for the film, but might just as well have been a trailer assembled by the TV station to advertise the show.)

It is quite likely the channel I saw this announcement on was [Tele 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tele_5), a channel that has somewhat specialized on showing "B movies"/direct-to-DVD productions/somehwat older and/or cheapish movies, in particular, regularly creature horror movies that fall into one of those aforementioned categories.

The one scene that stayed in my memory was the closing scene of the trailer: The scene starts with a camera pan (I think downwards into some kind of a vertical chute, but I may be mistaken about the exact presentation), at the bottom of which there is a mermaid. The background music rises gradually in pitch in such a way that it introduces a scream of the mermaid. Said scream beings sounding like a woman's voice (in pain/anguish?), but then transforms into a very unhuman-sounding voice<sup>1</sup>.

As far as I remember, the mermaid appeared to have at least a superficially human upper body in the trailer. That is, it looked more or less like a human woman (not sure about minor things like teeth or eyes), not like a remotely human-like monster. I cannot completely rule out the trailer gave a wrong impression in that regard, though.

**What I think it's not:**

- [*She-Creature*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0274659)
- [*Siren*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1548635)

---

<sup>1</sup>: The memory of which still manages to send chills down my spine, but I presume that is too subjective an impression to help in identifying this movie.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum: I am fully aware I know very little about this film. However, I am not quite sure which parts of that checklist I have *not* answered within the sparse recollection I have of this film. Except maybe "Tell us what it isn't" - I will try to exclude some other mermaid movies that I know aren't that movie.

Comment: I was thinking you could be a bit more visually descriptive about the mermaid.

Comment: @Valorum: You're right, that was an aspect I hadn't mentioned yet. Duly added - although unfortunately, without having seen the entire movie, but just a trailer, I may be missing important aspects of the overall story.

Comment: I remember many unpleasant things about a made-for-TV movie called [She Creature](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiHgfvA2vfcAhXS6J8KHRm9DsUQtwIIJzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DWUgNerSNKcs&usg=AOvVaw31BK9KsXDWHkrPZpLNAW4N).  The trailer ends with an unpleasant screaming sound.  Mermaid creature can assume a human-like form at will, but looks rather different in native form.  Transformation with screaming sounds is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmiymJeOfVY),

Comment: @DoscoJones: I watched this movie just a day ago (hoping to find what I'm looking for), and I don't think it's that one. The scream at [00:29](https://youtu.be/KmiymJeOfVY?t=29) admittedly sounds very similar to what I recall. Neither in that scene nor in any other scene in the movie the scream is introduced by a fittingly rising melody in the background score, though, and the scream I remember also lasted quite a bit longer than these (almost cut-off) brief screams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be [Nymph](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt3171764/) which aired on Tele 5 in 2016. In the official trailer I could not find the mentioned scene, but it is a creature horror / splatter movie that features a mermaid with a human upper half.

Comment: Wow. I *think* that might be the one. I'll postpone accepting this answer until I get some confirmation somehow, though (trying to get my hands on the film, or find some more excerpts from it).

Comment: Confirmed! It appears the movie was called *Mamula* in its original language (Serbian), and released as *Killer Mermaid* in English (*Nymph* being the title used for the German release). The scene that I remembered was the one at the end of [this video](https://youtu.be/WCW0eX6SupQ?t=244). So it was not as uniform a camera pan as I had thought, and the music was more of the mermaid's singing, until a full orchestral score unfolded synchronously with her scream ... slightly misremembered then ;) How did you find out that movie aired on Tele 5 in 2016, by the way?

Comment: I was searching for "Tele 5 Meerjungfrau" and sifted through the results for anything horror related. This lead me to schnittberichte.com where there was a comparison between the cut and uncut versions aired on Tele 5and also mentioned the date when it aired.